# How do I configure the md-select component in ember-cli-materialize? What do the options mean?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

The example code on the [online demo site](http://mike.works/ember-cli-materialize/#/forms) gives the following example:

```
{{md-select content=frameworks
    value=framework
    label="Framework"
    prompt="Please choose..."
    optionLabelPath="content.value"
    optionValuePath="content" class="col s12"}}
```

Is `frameworks` is some sort of Array on the model/route? I tried defining frameworks like this: `frameworks: ["Option 1","Option 2"]`
and `frameworks: [{text:"Option 1",value:"1"},{text:""Option 2"",value:"2"}]` but I still get only the empty select element with the default placeholder.

How do the `optionLabelPath` and `optionValuePath` options work?

**TLDR;** How to configure the options (and associated values) on the material select element from ember-cli-materialize addon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content is the array to make options from.

```
organismContent: [
        { value: 'F', display_name: 'Fungi' },
        { value: 'A', display_name: 'Alveolata (alveolates)' },
        { value: 'B', display_name: 'Bryophyta (mosses)' },
]
```

In template you would use something like this

```
    ...
    content=organismContent // Array to iterate over
    optionLabelPath="content.display_name" // user sees this field
    optionValuePath="content.value" // user picks this field
    value=run.organism // where the user selected value goes to 
    ...

    ...
    content=organismContent // Array to iterate over
    optionLabelPath="content.display_name" // user sees this field
    xxx // No need value path here
    selection=run.organism // user selects the whole object
    ...
```

Where *optionValuePath* is the objects property "value" which gets binded to value=blah . If you use *selection=blah* instead of *value=blah* it selects the whole object with "display_name" and "value". First usecase (*value=*)  is when your object selection is string and the second one (*selection=*) would be when you're using foreign keys (belongsTo).

```
      export default Ember.Route.extend({    
            model: function() {
                var store = self.get('store');

                    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                       organismContentFromServer: store.find('somemodel', 1) // you can access this via model.organismContentFromServer
                    });

            },

            setupController: function(controller, model) {
                this._super(controller, model);

                controller.setProperties({
                    organismContent: [], // This property is now accessible in template
                });
            }
    });
```

Binding controller and model properties to component

```
{{analysis/analysis-data   <--- This is a component
        run=model.run        <--- This is a model property
        componentorganismContent=organismContent    <-- This is a controller property
}}
```

now in component hbs

i can do `componentorganismContent.length` and it accesses controller's `organismContent.` Or if i do `{{run}}` it accesses model's hook `"Run"` If you get the last part ember will be much easier for you ;)

Comment: I tried doing this by adding the array as a member of the route and put the config you have suggested inside the `{{md-select.. }}` tags. But I ended up with this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined (materialize.js 2836)`. Could this be because the jQuery initialization (which happens under the hood to initialize the select) happening before the template is fully rendered? Or is it something to do with where the array comes from?

Comment: I changed `{{md-select content=organismContent
optionLabelPath="content.display_name"
optionValuePath="content.value"
value=run.organism
class="col s12"}}` to `{{md-select content=organismContent
value=organism
label="Framework"
prompt="Please choose..."
optionLabelPath="content.display_name"
optionValuePath="content.value" class="col s12"}}` and the error stopped happening. But now (again!!) only the placeholder is there "Please choose.." but no other options..

Comment: Try {{organismContent.length}} to see if you have access to the array in your template. Can you get it to work with ember select?

Comment: Btw you said As a member of the route. Does it mean it is inside the "model" function hook? If this is so then you need to use model. reference before using the array like so - content=model.myarray

Comment: `export default Ember.Route.extend({
  organismContent: function(){
    return [
      { value: 'F', display_name: 'Fungi' },
      { value: 'A', display_name: 'Alveolata (alveolates)' },
      { value: 'B', display_name: 'Bryophyta (mosses)' }
    ]
});` Was what I had tried. I also tried declaring `organismContent` as a plain array but neither worked. However, changing organismContent to model (both in the route.js and the template) fixed it and now I can see the options. Does it HAVE to be a model property hook? Won't any structure work?

Comment: @ChiragRavindra This means you have no access to your array in template. Updated my answer for correct way of using route.

Comment: Thanks, @kristjan it works for me now. I'm not using ember data but I made the property available on the controller. So to clarify: model properties are not available on the template and must be set on the controller? But components can access model properties (as I have used them before and Ember in general is moving out of using explicit contollers?)

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Back in the day you could use controller properties everywhere in templates. Automatically if u used {{blah}} it meant you are accessing controller. Now in new ember in order to use controller properties you could bind them via template (the best way really) . Updated answer